# Copying subdirectories with -r option not working

Tags: 11.10, command-line, bash

I just want to copy the contents of a directory and the subdirectories within it over to another directory in a Bash shell. I assumed `cp -r` would do this.

However, this isn't working:

```
cp -r $BASEDIR/Upload/Temp $BASEDIR/backup
```

The directory `Temp` has a bunch of files and directories in it. But after I run this command, I only get the *files* in `backup`. No directories are copied.

I'm also having the same problem with the `-r` option with a `zip` command. In the same Bash shell, I've got these commands:

```
cd $BASEDIR/Upload/Temp
zip -r $BASEDIR/Backup2/backup2.zip .
```

When I look at the contents of `backup2.zip`, all it has are the files, no subdirs. *(I `cd` into the directory because it's the only way I know to store files in a zip without getting the absolute path stored as well, which I don't need.)*

What am I not getting about the `-r` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

- `cp -R` maybe that will work, or
- `cp -rf`, you can also try
- `cp -av` origin_folder destiny_folder –
- But `cp -r /home/hope/files/* /home/hope/backup`, should have worked.

Comment: cp -R worked. Strange that case made a difference, but... weirdness sometimes happens.

Comment: the `-r` and `-R` are equivalent in the Ubuntu `cp` (coming from GNU coreutils), so probably you were making some other mistake.